# canvas drawBitmap only part of image

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

How do I draw a part of a bitmap using canvas with canvas.drawBitmap() ?

For example I have the following bitmap

[image]

And I need to draw only this part

[image]

Is it possible to do with canvas.drawBitmap or I need something else?

Comment: If you just need to draw a wedge like that, you could use one of the `Canvas#drawArc()` methods instead.

Comment: updated question. Can it be done now with BitmapShader?

Comment: combine my first comment and @MikeM. comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [PorterDuff modes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode.html). Check the following diagram to understand it:
[image]

In example you can paint the bitmap and then eliminate part of it painting a mask in SRC-OUT mode.
Or you can paint the mask and then paint the bitmap with DST-OUT.

There are several options, just test them.

Here is an example of how to apply the mode to your paints

```
Paint mPaint;

mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT);
```

Comment: How can I do with 2 bitmaps?
c.drawBitmap(bitmap1, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 150), null);
c.drawBitmap(bitmap2, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 150), null);

tried this, but got black square
c.drawBitmap(bitmap1, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 150), null);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
c.drawBitmap(bitmap2, null, new Rect(0, 0, 100, 150), paint);

Comment: @Droid you dont need 2 Bitmaps, just use BitmapShader